# WP7 - How to embed my xap in a webpage

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xap

I have made a Windows Phone 7 app and I would like to embed it in a webpage.

I found two examples to help explain what I want to do:

http://www.lifewaresolutions.com/deluxe_moon_demo_wp7.html

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/WindowsPhone/samples/start.htm

I have looked at the page sources for both of these websites and have tried to mimic what they have down, but the farthest I have gotten is a webpage  with a silverlight app in the middle, but my app doesn't start.

I am not that familiar with web development, but if someone could help me create a simple html page with my wp7 app embedded in it, that would be great.

Comment: Looks just rewritten in Silverlight.

Comment: I thought that at first too, but the Moon Demo link seems to be using their xap as the source for the silverlight application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight desktop computer plugin can't execute Windows Phone Silverlight apps.

The two example websites embed a "classic" Silverlight app within a fake Windows Phone chrome.

So basically what you can do to have something similar is:

- Create a new Silverlight 4 "classic" project
- Implement your app (you can [share code between the new project and your existing WP7 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767647/is-it-possible-to-share-code-between-a-silverlight-web-app-and-windows-phone-7-ap))
- Retemplate the controls to make them look like the Windows Phone ones
- Embed the app within a WP7 chrome on a website